# How to add jars to the classpath of the CloudFoundry java buildpack using Java Main

Tags: postgresql, jakarta-ee, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I'm currently working on deployment of a single manifest file configuration deployment of multiple WAR and Java Batch files to IBM Bluemix (CloudFoundry).

The idea is that I just run "cf push" and then some magic happens and I'm done.

This works pretty well for WAR files running on IBM Liberty and also a PostgreSQL service bound to it but unfortunately doesn't work for the Standalone - Java Main class since I don't know how to put additional jars to the classpath.

This is my manifest.yml:

```
#declared-services:
#  postgresql:
#    label: elephantsql
#    plan: turtle

applications:
- name: multipleWarDeploy1
  disk: 1024M
  path: Web/Web.war
  memory: 256M
  instances: 2
  host: sixendpointURL
  services:
  - postgresql
- name: batch
  disk: 1024M
  path: Batch/Batch.jar
  buildpack: java_buildpack 
  memory: 256M
  no-route: true
  instances: 1
  services:
  - postgresql
```

As you can see, the Java Main buildpack used for the Batch application only allows me to reference a single jar file so I'm wondering how to upload the lib folder containing the jars. I've already put the references into the MANIFEST.MF file of Batch.jar - so this works locally where the lib folder is present - but not remote since this folder doesn't get pushed to Bluemix, only the Batch.jar file.

Any ideas?

tnx a lot
romeo

Answer (score 1):

I would use a tool like one-jar to package all my jars into one jar.

http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be pushing a package of your liberty instance, as allowed option for liberty runtime.
You can create the liberty server zip by executing 'server package zip-name --include=usr'
Then you can push the zip using: 'cf push app-name -p zip-name'

For full documentation about this option start from
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#starters/liberty/index.html#liberty

Here is the documentation about the available options for pushing a liberty application:
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/liberty/index.html#optionsforpushinglibertyapplications

Answer (score 0):

I just tested having two batch war files in a server directory and then pushing that directory to a single Bluemix application with the specified server.xml. Both applications worked properly once pushed.

Create a directory structure like below:

[image: Directory Structure Example]

Then add your war files into the apps folder (*my example had the two sample war files I used*) and add each application to your server.xml file.

The two lines I added to my server.xml are shown below:

```
<application name="BonusPayout" context-root="/BonusPayout" type="war" location="BonusPayout.war"/>
<application name="SimpleBatchJob" context-root="/SimpleBatchJob" type="war" location="SimpleBatchJob.war"/>
```

and finally run the following command while in the parent directory of the defaultServer directory you just made:

cf push YourBluemixAppName -p defaultServer

This will push the entire directory with all of your war files included.